# Sending a template email from a RESTful APEX service and including the contact's name in it

Tags: apex, rest-api, email-template, permissions, apexrest

I have this RESTful controller enabled on my APEX Site to test email templates:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Activations/*')
global class ActivationController {

    @HttpGet
    @HttpPost
    global static String email() {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTemplateId('00X3B000000HxnRUAS');
        mail.setTargetObjectId('0033B00000BwGiiQAF');
        mail.setWhatId('a033B000001P8vMQAS');
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

I am trying to use this email template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Subject" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Activation__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<html>
   <body>
      {!recipient.FirstName}
   </body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id:
>   [] Class.ActivationController.email

If I delete `{!recipient.FirstName}` from the template, I don't get the error anymore.

How can I show the contact's first name in the email? Is this a permissions thing? What am I doing wrong? **Please note that the IDs I am using are absolutely valid. In addition, they reference the correct type of object they need to reference in order to populate SingleEmailMessage parameters correctly.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like [a known bug with relatedTo.{x}](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SdBfAAK) fields.

As a workaround, I've added a Contact object onto the `relatedToType` and used `{!relatedTo.Contact__r.FirstName}`.